# Call to a member function count() on a non-object (Laravel 5)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a list of projects, where I can click on and it (needs to) show the project name, and the list of the projects' tasks (ToDo application)

But when I click on a certain project I get this error.

(The "H2" project name will show up)

```
h2>{{{ $project->name }}}</h2>

@if ( !$project->tasks->count())
    There are no tasks for this project.
@else
    <ul>
        @foreach( $project->tasks as $task)
            <li><a href="{{ route('projects.tasks.show', [$project->slug, $task->slug]) }}">{{ $task->name }}</a></li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Comment: try `!count($project->tasks)` instead of `!$project->tasks->count()`. If you want to be able to use your version, $project->tasks needs to be an object that implements the count method. So you need to implement the interface Countable.

Comment: This triggers the 'if' statement whilst this project has tasks, so it needs to go into the 'else' statement

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`$project->tasks` is an array and you cant call `count()` on the array. So try with -

```
count($project->tasks)
```

Comment: I get this error using `count($project->tasks)` `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\wamp\www\company\resources\views\projects\show.blade.php)`   And with `!count($project->tasks)` it will always trigger the if statement

Comment: It gives `null` but in my database it has clearly tasks linked

Comment: That means there is something wrong with relations or fetching data.

Comment: If the `$project->tasks` is null or empty it will throw an error in PHP 7.2. Reference http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php

Comment: `sizeOf` be the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try count($project->tasks)==0

```
h2>{{{ $project->name }}}</h2>

@if ( count($project->tasks)==0)
    There are no tasks for this project.
@else
    <ul>
        @foreach( $project->tasks as $task)
            <li><a href="{{ route('projects.tasks.show', [$project->slug, $task->slug]) }}">{{ $task->name }}</a></li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your issue is resolved but this might help someone else :D

The following piece of code might work for you, but it's not that we can't call count() on the array.

```
count($project->tasks)
```

Instead of this

```
h2>{{{ $project->name }}}</h2>

@if ( !$project->tasks->count()) // tasks is plural -> wrong.
    There are no tasks for this project.
@else
    <ul>
        @foreach( $project->tasks as $task) // here too!
            <li><a href="{{ route('projects.tasks.show', [$project->slug, $task->slug]) }}">{{ $task->name }}</a></li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Try doing this

```
h2>{{{ $project->name }}}</h2>

@if ( !$project->task->count())
    There are no tasks for this project.
@else
    <ul>
        @foreach( $project->task as $task)
            <li><a href="{{ route('projects.tasks.show', [$project->slug, $task->slug]) }}">{{ $task->name }}</a></li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I use collection for empty objects this could work better

in my controller

```
if ($search) {
    $taks = MODEL::search($search)->get();
} else {
    $tasks = collect([]);
}
```

in my view

```
@if ($tasks->count())
    <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach($tasks as $task)
            <li>info and action</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@else
    <p class="text-danger">Error message</p>
@endif
```