# Call to a member function count() on int in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to count the total number of new students created in this month and the number of online students in this month

```php
public function index () 
  {
     $month = Carbon::now()->month;
     $members = Member::getStudents();
     $saleareas = Member::getSaleAreas();
     Order::getTotalCardOnSaleAreas($saleareas);
     foreach ($members as $member) {
        $newstudent = $member->created_at->month;
        $online = $member->updated_at->month;
        if($month == $newstudent){
            $members = $members->count();
        }
        if($month == $online){
            $onl= $members->count(); // error           
        }
        $orders = Order::where('member_id',$member->id)->get();
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            $neworder = $order->created_at->month;
            if($month == $neworder && $order->status = 'active'){
                $orders = $orders->count();
            };
        }
     }
      return view('admin.dashboard.index', compact('members','orders','onl','saleareas'));
        }
```

It appears an error: Call to a member function count() on int

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to a member function count() on a non-object (Laravel 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941759/call-to-a-member-function-count-on-a-non-object-laravel-5)

Answer (score 1):

it's because of the first if,

```
if($month == $newstudent){
            $members = $members->count(); //here, the $members changed to an int
}
```

and then you try to count the $members that were integer now, so you get the `Call to a member function count() on int` error.

I think you can count the data this way :

`$total = count(DB::select(DB::raw("Select * from table where *put your condition here* ")));`

Comment: How to fix it ?